# Ajax add to cart giving 302 header status and not adding to cart magento2

Tags: magento2

I am using ajax add to cart in magento2 and my items are not getting added to cart.

The issue I am seeing is that I am getting 302 as response header from server due to which the items are not getting added.

When we are getting 200 from server its getting added.

Kindly suggest!

Comment: Something in your system causes a redirect to a different URL, and with a 302 the browser will follow that redirect by switching the method from POST to GET, so that you lose any POST data in the process ... (But don’t ask us what that something might be now, because with the information you have given that is nearly impossible to tell or even guess.)

Comment: Nothing is causing the redirect. I have checked this in network and console. So the reason which you are telling is not the case

Comment: _“Nothing is causing the redirect. I have checked this in network and console”_ - you said yourself that you do see a 302 header ... is that not the case any more now, or what?